# DOS If FINSTR is found set variable to that line and then echo variable?

Tags: dos, batch-file

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /c /i "apples" "test.txt"') do set varMWG=%%f
REM echo %varMWG%

if %varMWG% EQU 1 (
    @echo TRUE
) else (
    @echo FALSE
)
```

instead of echoing TRUE or FALSE I want to echo the variables line if the string is found and still echo FALSE if it is not found.

test.txt contains

```
fdgsdf
hgsfrtgyr
apples
fdsgfghs
erwyuweu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to echo the lines that match or echo FALSE if no lines match (in other words, you don't need the variable), then

```
findstr /ilc:"apples" "test.txt" || echo FALSE
```

Remember that there could be multiple lines that match your search.

If you need a variable containing the last found line, then:

```
set "varMWG="
for /f "delims=" %%S in ('findstr /ilc:"apples" "test.txt"') do set "varMWG=%%S"
if defined varMWG (echo %varMWG%) else echo FALSE
```

Note - Delayed expansion would be safer. ECHO using regular expansion can fail depending on the content of varMWG.

If you need a variable containing the first found line, then:

```
set "varMWG="
for /f "delims=" %%S in ('findstr /ilc:"apples" "test.txt"') do (
  set "varMWG=%%S"
  echo %%S
  goto :break
)
:break
if not defined varMWG echo FALSE
```

This last option would not ever need delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

If by "echo the variables line" you mean echo the search string "apples", then the following code should suffice:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in (test.txt) do (
if %%f EQU apples (echo %%f
) else echo false
)
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
false
false
apples
false
false
```

Comment: I believe a line like "Green apples are sour" should also match. Your code of course doesn't work that way. Also, I think the OP only wants 1 FALSE line if the search string is not found anywhere in the file.

Comment: @dbenham output testing with the line "green apples are sour" at the end of test.txt:
`false`
`false`
`apples`
`false`
`false`
`false`

Comment: Yes, and I believe the correct answer should have the entire green apple phrase in place of the last false.

Comment: @dbenham Oh yes, I guess my interpretation of the problem was different. Your answer works fine assuming that is what is need.